# how to debug scala spark code in intelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm new to Scala and Spark, and current working on a scala spark jobs project, one thing frustrated me is I don't know how to debug the code in IntelliJ like I did with java.

after I imported the scala project, one thing i noticed is the spark-jobs folder was not marked as source code folder even though some other sub folders in the same module are market as source code folder.

```
-- utility (marked as source code folder)
   -- event-sender (marked as source code folder)
   -- spark-jobs (not marked as source code folder)
      -- src
         --main
           -- resources
           -- scala
              -- com
                -- example
                   -- spark
                      -- jobs
```

as I checked the spark job I'm working on , there is no main method.

```
class DailyExport(
    env: String,
    )(implicit sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext, logger: SparkJobLogger)
    extends JobAudit
    with PartitionedWriter {

  def run(): Unit = ...

object DailyExport extends App with SparkJobParameters {

  {
    for {
      env          <- getStringParameter("environment", 0, args)
    } yield {
      val jobConfig               = SparkJobConfig.fromConfig.exportConfig
      ...

      new DailyExport(
        jobConfig = jobConfig
      ).run()
    }
  }.fold(
    error => {
      println(s"Some provided parameters are wrong: $error")
      sys.exit(-1)
    },
    identity
  )
}
```

however there is a main method defined in 'App'

```
trait App extends DelayedInit {
...
@deprecatedOverriding("main should not be overridden", "2.11.0")
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    this._args = args
    for (proc <- initCode) proc()
    if (util.Properties.propIsSet("scala.time")) {
      val total = currentTime - executionStart
      Console.println("[total " + total + "ms]")
    }
  }
```

then I right clicked on the job that I'm working to choose 'Run..', it complained

```
'Error: Could not find or load main class com.exmaple.spark.jobs.DailyExport'
```

this is so different from Java, can anyone tell me how to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

In Scala there's different ways to define a main class. One is to define a main method in an `object`, similar to Java. The other is to extend the `App` trait, and just write the application code right into the class, as was done with `DailyExport` in your example. So you should be able to run this class normally as main class, and you should also see a "Run" icon next to the class in IntelliJ (not the main method in the super class, which is an implementation detail of the `App` trait).

If you run it that way, and you still get the error, it's possible you're running into [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13401) in IntelliJ. Try running it again, possibly after switching windows and checking the compile output is really where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Please have inspect the target folders that get generated by IntelliJ. Make sure that the package structure is maintained.

If the problem still persists, try doing a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA has its own debugger for debugging scala. You can use INTELLIJ IDEA Debugger or sbt shell to debug the issues.

More information is [here.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html)